# Not opening folder in localhost

Tags: php

I just installed WAMP server to start practicing PHP. I created a folder in www directory. However, when I try to run the file from localhost it does not run.

For ex, I created a folder "test" in www directory. I saved an php file called "test.php" inside the test folder. Basically I have saved it in www --> test --> test.php.

I started localhost in my browser. I found test folder there. But when I click that test folder, instead of opening as "localhost/test", it is opening as just "test/". How to make sure that the folder, when clicked inside localhost, should open as "localhost/

When I type as "localhost/test" in my browser, it works fine. But when I go to localhost and click on "test" folder it does not open.

Please help me to overcome this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just create new virtual host in wamp using your current directory path to test directory.